# Controller helper_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering why someone should use helper_method inside a controller to create a helper method, instead of creating the "normal" way, which is inside the helper file. What the pros and cons of that?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`helper_method` is useful when the functionality is something that's used between both the controller and the view. A good example is something like `current_user`.

If the method deals more with controller logic and not formatting then it belongs in the controller. Something like `current_user` would be shared between all controllers so it should be defined in the `ApplicationController`.

True "helper" methods deal with the view and handle things like formatting and template logic. These are seldom needed in the controller and they belong in their own module under app/helpers. You can include these in your controller when needed, but you end up with the whole module worth of view helper methods available to your controller.

Answer (score 14):

to share methods between controller and view you have several options:

- use view_context http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context
- define it in the controller and make available in view by the helper_method class method http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method
- define it in a shared module and include/extend