# (Rails) Accessing methods from a controller in a different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controllers

In Rails, how do I go about accessing, for example, a method from the Post controller in the Home view? I am pretty sure that it involves helpers, but I can't seem to get it right.

I am sorry if this question has already been asked, but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: You are right. Post controller is reserved for Post view, so Home view can't use methods from Post controller. What method do you want to access ? What would you like to do? You can do most of what you need to do in HomeHelper by creating the necessary methods there.

Comment: I am trying to follow the Getting Started Guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). For right now, I am trying to list the names of each Post on my Home view.

Comment: You aren't using a method of the Post controller as much as you should be using a method of the Post model class.   @posts = Post.all from within your Home controller is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can either put the method in a helper module or use the helper_method in your controller, (check out this past [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549713/controller-helper-method) for more info about the helper_method.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the method you want to access from `PostController` is one of the
   7 CRUD functions, I suggest you figure out what functionality you
   want to duplicate and move that into a separate method and do step 2.
2. Move the method you want to share into `PostsHelper`. You can then
   `include PostsHelper` in `HomeController` and use the functions from
   there.