# Rails controller for application.rhtml.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm doing an app with session management and I want to display if the user is logged in or not at the top of every page. I have the front-end for this in application.rhtml.erb, is there any controller/method that will let me set a site-wide variable? As it is I define the condition for every individual page, there has to be a better way.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your method in the `application_helper.rb` file. That'll be available site-wide.

Comment: `application_helper.rb` will only affect views, I believe.  I think you want to add code to `application_controller.rb` if you want it to be available from all other controller.  If you *also* want it to be available in views, add a line after the method definition `helper :my_method`.  See a good post on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549713/controller-helper-method