# Rails returning full object instead of integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails's `pluralize` method was not working like I wanted (words not in english) so I set out to try my own solution. I started out simple with this method in `ApplicationController`:

```
def inflect(number, word)
  if number.to_i > 1
    word = word + "s"
  end      
  return "#{number} #{word}"
end
```

And called it as such in my view:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= inflect(article.word_count, "word") %>
  <%= inflect(article.paragraph_count, "paragraph") %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

But this got me:

```
undefined method `inflect' for #<#<Class:0x3ea79f8>:0x3b07498>
```

I found it weird that it referenced a full-fledged object when I thought it was supposed to be just an integer, so I tested it on the console:

```
article = Article.first
=> (object hash)
article.word_count
=> 10
article.word_count.is_a?(Integer)
=> true
```

So I threw in a quick `words = article.word_count.to_i`, but it doesn't throw a TypeError, it actually doesn't do anything, and still returns the same error: ``` undefined method ``inflect' for #<#<Class:0x3ea79f8>:0x3b07498> ``` in reference to the `` `inflect(article.word_count, "word") `` line.

Then I thought maybe `inflect` was already a Rails method and it was some sort of naming conflict, but doesn't matter what I change the method's name to, it keeps giving me the same error: ``` undefined method ``whatever' for #<#<Class:0x3ea79f8>:0x3b07498> ```

I then tested it on the console and it worked fine. What's going on?

Comment: Put your inflect method in ApplicationHelper, not ApplicationController

Comment: @house9 That did it, thanks! Can you expand on why exactly I should have put it there, and not on ApplicationController?

Comment: ...added some additional information as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Put your inflect method in ApplicationHelper, not ApplicationController

by default all code in your helpers are mixed into the views

the view is its own entity, it is not part of the controller, when a view instance gets created (automatically when your controller action executes) it gets passed any instance variables you define in your controller action, but does not have access to controller methods directly

NOTE: you can define methods in your controller to expose them to your views by using the `helper_method` macro - see this post for more info on that - [Controller helper_method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549713/controller-helper-method)

but in general you would define the view helper methods in the helpers classes and not in the controller